# How to embed a variable result in erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :content, class: "js-content-hidden hidden-response-to-comment-<%= comment.id %>" %>
```

Notice `<%= comment.id %>` in the class name. It produces an error. How can I embed that id in the class string?

Comment: You should use `<%= f.hidden_field :content, class: "js-content-hidden hidden-response-to-comment-#{comment.id}" %>` if `comment.id` exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that any code between `<%` and `%>` in an erb file is ruby, so you can't *embed* more code, what you want is *string interpolation* (the value for `class` in your hidden field is a string). VAD answer should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :content, class: "js-content-hidden hidden-response-to-comment-#{comment.id}" %>
```